# Java C# socket communication

Tags: java, c#, sockets

I am working on a Java-C# socket communication and I would like to send the coordinates of a C# object to java periodically. The problem is that the java client Stream only reads the coordinates (20 mile long buffer) when I close the connection. I would like the connection to remain open and the coordinates to update without having to open and close this connection all the time.
P.S. This was working but I somehow deleted the previous C# script I was using now I cannot figure it out.

The Java `LocationRequester`, will `connect` to the server and then periodically call `getline()` and pass it to coordinates. The connect part works and `getline()` only completes if I close the connection, otherwise it hangs. When I close the connection I get a super long row of coordinates.

```
public Socket clientSocket;
BufferedReader inputBuff;
String hostName;
int hostPort;

public LocationListener(String host, int port) {
    hostName = host;
    hostPort = port;
}

public void connect()
{           
    try {
         clientSocket = new Socket(hostName, hostPort);
         System.out.println("Connected to"+clientSocket.toString());
        InputStream input = clientSocket.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(input);
        inputBuff = new BufferedReader(reader);
        String str;
    }
     catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String getLine() {           
    String rstring = "";
    try {
        rstring = inputBuff.readLine();
        System.out.println(rstring);
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return rstring;
}
```

C# code seems to be where the problem is.

```
    private void Start()
    {
        IPAddress address = IPAddress.Any;
        server = new TcpListener(address, 9999);
        server.Start();

        client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        StartCoroutine(SendCords());
    }

    private IEnumerator SendCords()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(transform.position.ToString());
            stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
            stream.Flush();
            // client.Close();
            Debug.Log("Sending "+transform.position);
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The java code is reading a line. That means it will block until it gets a line feed character '\n'. And I guess your C# code is not adding a line feed. In my opinion, if you add a line feed character in the end, to your C# message payload, the java code should get the information and come out of the wait. Give a try.

Answer (score 1):

@ferosekhanj has already said very well. I add that the function of`BufferedReader.readLine()` will stop reading at'\n' and also at EOF. This is why when your C# program close the Socket, and your java program will receive a super long row of coordinates.